# ROW_NUMBER() doesn't return good number of items first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am getting from database list of items ordered by descending date.
I use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to get 50 by 50 items. 
First time I need to get items from 1-50 than 51-100 etc.
I have in database items with type 1 and those are items that I get.
There is thousands of those items in database.
So when I first time call stored procedure I pass it number one (number from which item to get next 50).
So this should return me first 50 items. Now I add to where clause `RowNum < 1+50` but row numbers that I get from query are: `35,37,38,43,44,45,55,67` etc. so my stored procedure returns me only items from `35 to 45`.
I think I make some stupid miss in my query but can't find it.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Products.CreatedOnDate DESC ) AS RowNum, Products.*          
          FROM      Products          
          WHERE     Products.CreatedOnDate <= GETDATE()
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum < 1+50 -- here I use parameter but currently I hardcode '1'
    AND ProductTypeId = 1
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: It seems you want tofo pagination? Why you don't just use TOP 50, and for the next you make TOP 100 inside, then TOP 50 outside and change the ORDER.

Comment: I don't know. Older developers told me that it's better for performance to use ROW_NUMBER(), I can use TOP X if there is no performance issues.
@Mitch Wheat: on what code do you mean?

Comment: Please read this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2012/02/02/conor-vs-window-functions-sequence-ranking-functions-order-of-operations.aspx) written by Conor Cunningham.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are filtering on `ProductTypeID` but the inner query with the `Row_Number` does not:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Products.CreatedOnDate DESC ) AS RowNum
                 , Products.*          
          FROM     Products          
          WHERE    Products.CreatedOnDate <= GETDATE()
          AND      ProductTypeId = 1
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
AND     RowNum < 1+50 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: I knew that it was something that I miss :) Thanks